# Need help with searching a file in mutillidae webserver

Tags: penetration-test

My school has setup a webserver with mutillidae installed for us to train our hacking skills. Our goal is to find a text file. After some hacking done, I'm currently able to use remote desktop connection and login to the webserver with administrator rights. However, after searching everywhere i still couldn't find the text file. I'm sure it's not inside the webserver. 
Is it possible that the file is on other machine that only the webserver is able to connect to it? If so, how? 
What are the possible clues i can gather from the webserver in order to find the text file?

Comment: What information do you have on the text file?  Do you have a file name, or just some idea of its contents?  If you have a file name, do the following from an elevated command prompt (presuming the target is running Windows):  `cd /d C:\ & dir filename /a /s`.  Repeat for each drive letter until found.  If you don't find it this way, it's probably not there.

Comment: I only know the filename. It's called confidential.txt. I tried the command you gave.. it says file not found instantly.

Comment: It shouldn't be instant.  It should take some time for the system to search the entire partition.  Sounds like you've got some other limitation to your access, possibly.

Comment: @shaun what is the operating system?

Comment: It's windows xp 3.

Comment: Then @Iszi's command is the way to go: `cd /d C:\ & dir confidential.txt /a /s`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have permission to comment yet so I'll have to add this as an answer.

1. You can try using the command `net use` and `net view` to see what
   the server is currently accessing over the network.
2. You could go to start->run->compmgmt.msc then look at Shared Folders and see if anything is currently open on a different server from the current server you're on. (thanks Iszi for the shorter path to shares)
3. Another kind of odd possibility is that the file `confidential.txt` is stored in an [Alternate Data Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) in which case you can use [Sysinternals Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) to search for existing streams.

It's hard to help in this situation because there could be any number of different things used to hide the file; there could even be a "rootkit" like system driver installed to hide files from user view but depending on the level of the challenge, that might not be the case.

Comment: To shorten the route to folder shares, run `compmgmt.msc` instead of starting from `mmc`.

Comment: after executing net view command, i only see the computer itself. For the shares, i went to look at all the shares but still cannot find it :(

Comment: @shaun are there any kind of "rules of engagement" for this or a set of instructions or knowns for this assignment? Does the assignment guarantee anything about the file `confidential.txt`?

Comment: nope. No special instructions were given. My teacher is sure there is confidential.txt hidden.Well, i tried pivoting but end up stuck to login smb client. Could it be steganography?

Comment: @shaun It could be, but like I said, it could by any number of things. There are a ton of ways to hide files on a system. Did you try searching for Alternate Data Streams? Without any guidelines from your teacher I would think it couldn't be too hidden because once you get into the realm of steg and other such techniques, it really is a needle in a hay stack when you're looking at a whole server which could have over a hundred thousand files on it. I'm afraid we'd (at least I would) need more context surrounding the challenge and what has been provided to you.

Comment: I tried searching for alternate data streams. No confidential.txt is found. Here is some information, I extracted the important points: Students are to only retrieve and decode Confidential.txt file.XXX requests that you retrieve a file called Confidential.txt from its network. To ensure that you retrieve the correct file, you have to inform XXX’s executives what is said in the file. No other further information is given except that XXX has a website at publicIpAddress/XXX

Comment: @shaun does the website have a database back-end? If it does, the file could be stored inside the database; which would explain why all the suggested techniques so far have not produced any results. Is the website some sort of Content Management System (CMS)?

Comment: Erm no the website is based on mutillidae web application but it is slightly altered. The website does have database back end however we still cannot access it. The database is on a private ip address 192.168.100.2 based on the configuration file. I tried accessing it using the remote desktop web browser 192.168.100.2:3306, but it show me a packet error message.

Comment: @shaun If you have access to the web server via remote desktop, then you can get to the servers with private IPs from the web server. Also, port 3306 is not remote desktop, it's MySQL; you would need to connect to that port with the MySQL client tool from the command prompt or a GUI based MySQL front-end... if you need a username and password to connect to the MySQL database with, snoop around for the configuration files in the web application for a database connection string or settings. With the mutillidae app, try looking at `/config.inc` for the database username and password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4804/discussion-between-shaun-and-vane)